# Create a menu under a menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I am wondering if there is a way to have a menu under another menu in Drupal 7. Let's say I have a new menu called Blah and I want it to appear under the main menu item Top.

So I would end up with

```
Main Menu

|- Top
|---Blah Menu
|------ Blah Menu Item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious approach would be to have your main-menu built with sub-links.

If that doesn't work, you could:

edit your template to call the new menu right underneath the first.

or

add the new menu to the same block as your first menu (you may want to define new block areas for this)